# Java Object->String[] to String[]

Tags: java

I have an Object variable that contains a String[] array, and I am trying to do the following

```
String[] arr = ((String[])packet.getObject());
```

I however recieve the dreaded ClassCastException. What information do you guys need? My packet class looks as the following:

```
public class Packet implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private int type;
private Object object;

public Packet(int type, Object object) {
    this.type = type;
    this.object = object;
}

public int getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(int type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public Object getObject() {
    return object;
}

public void setObject(Object object) {
    this.object = object;
}
}
```

Any ideas? I'm trying to convert the Object into a String[].

Comment: What type is passed into the constructor of Paket at runtime (or set via setter)? I guess it is not a String[] ;)

Comment: Oh damn, thank you! Just realized it's inside another Class, DOH!

Comment: In which case, the ClassCastException will tell you which class you really have.

Answer (score 3):

If you get a ClassCastException, it means that the packet does NOT hold a `String[]`.

Execute the following code to see what it actually holds, then debug to see why and where the object is stored in the packet:

```
System.out.println(packet.getObject());
System.out.println(packet.getObject().getClass());
```

A debugger would give you this information without needing to modify the code.

Comment: Indeed it was not a String[] but another class I had it wrapped in, thanks :)